# Vuejs : v-if with object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement

I got a problem regardings a v-if v-else in a vuejs project.
THe component checking inside the CvData.experiences object if there is an object with the index but it seems to not work.

When i click on the button, the object [0] (for example) is created.
When i console.log(cvData.experiences) i've got the object 0 in cvData.experiences.
And when i click again on the same button, it removes the object 0 (that's what the function does)

here the code :

```
<v-btn
 v-if="cvData.experiences[index]"
 icon
 small
 outline
 color="primary"
 @click="addItem(index)"
>
 <v-icon>remove</v-icon>
</v-btn>
<v-btn
 v-else
 icon
 small
 outline
 color="primary"
 @click="addItem(index)"
>
 <v-icon>add</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

I've got the Add button, but when i click, it doesn't change.

So before i click : 
cvData.experiences[index] is undefined
after i click : 
cvData.experiences[index] is an object

Comment: give a more extended example

Comment: @AlbertAllagulov The problem is, because the data changes in the Parent, the data doesn't trigger the v-if condition .. so the Icon doesn"t change

Comment: How to this data is passed to the children? With properties? Or you use Vuex? If the data doesn't trigger, maybe this object isn't reactive.

Comment: @GabrielWillemann it's not from Vuex it's from the Parent with props. How can the children componen see if that object is updated in the Parent ?

Comment: You can use [.sync modifer](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier). Or you can use [Vue.observable](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) and share this object with the components.